# Heroku Error Logs for Ruby on Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

Noob Ruby on Rails Developer here, so please forgive my ignorance. So I am trying to get this app deployed on Heroku.

Currently my last four lines from my heroku logs are:

```
2013-04-22T01:50:19.459579+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec     rake db:migrate` by nevin.watkins@gmail.com
2013-04-22T01:50:22.560589+00:00 heroku[run.6823]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-04-22T01:50:22.560405+00:00 heroku[run.6823]: Awaiting client
2013-04-22T01:50:22.837077+00:00 heroku[run.6823]: State changed from starting to up
2013-04-22T01:50:38.906768+00:00 heroku[run.6823]: Process exited with status 0
2013-04-22T01:50:38.918254+00:00 heroku[run.6823]: State changed from up to complete
2013-04-22T01:50:43.330599+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"     method=GET path=/ host=eagerfans.com fwd="74.199.107.176" dyno= connect= service= status=503     bytes=
2013-04-22T01:50:43.340764+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 74.199.107.176 - - [22/Apr/2013:01:50:43     +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 601 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3)     AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.65 Safari/537.31" eagerfans.com
2013-04-22T01:50:43.482962+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 74.199.107.176 - - [22/Apr/2013:01:50:43     +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 503 601 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3)     AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.65 Safari/537.31" eagerfans.com
2013-04-22T01:50:43.479123+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"     method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=eagerfans.com fwd="74.199.107.176" dyno= connect= service=     status=503 bytes=
```

Again, I'm sorry if I have completely screwed this up. I assume it is something obvious that I missed along the way.

If you can please advise me that would be great. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this it will help you.hope it works for you.

http://benji.so/2012/11/27/a-guide-to-enki-heroku-deployment

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry that I'm just now replying. This really helped me out at the time.